# opensuse php-fpm lighttpd 403, is it a permissions issue?

Tags: php, linux, permissions, lighttpd, opensuse

So far I have configured php-fpm configured and is up and running
listening to port 9000

lighttpd is running and serves static files
the problem that I have seems to be a permissions issue, so i chmod 777 -R /srv
when I try to access index.php (which has phpinfo()) I get "access denied" in the browser.

in my fastcgi.conf I have

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "crunchyboy",
                "port" => 9000
        ))
)
```

if I use the browser to navigate to http://crunchyboy/index.php
I get "Access Denied" that shows up in the access log as a 403
if i make up a file name like doesnotexist.php eg http://crunchyboy/doesnotexist.php I get a 404 file not found. If you are wondering about crunchyboy its the name of the machine and I can access it on the LAN. eg http://crunchyboy/index.html is ok

if I stop the php-fpm with systemctl stop php-fpm and navigate to index.php I get
503 Service Unavailable

so to me it looks like lighttpd is able to make a request to php-fpm but for some reason the file cannot be accessed.

I've configured php-fpm with nginx and apache in the past (more than 5 years ago) and did not have this problem.

I am really stuck with this, so would appreciate help or atleast ideas on what I need to look at.

Both lighttpd and php-fpm are set to run as user: lighttpd group:lighttpd
Its on opensuse tumbleweed, recently updated

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a question about how to configure and operate lighthttpd and / or its PHP module.  That is off topic here, where we address questions about programming.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 777` is **never** the proper solution.

If you are running php-fpm, then php-fpm is running your application.  Check your php-fpm configuration.

My hunch is that you have not configured your firewall to allow access to public port 9000, or have not configured crunchyboy in DNS or /etc/hosts.  In any case, you should probably instead be using `127.0.0.1` instead of `crunchyboy`.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 9000
        ))
)
```

Comment: I had already tried localhost, I only changed it to crunchyboy and got the same result. I know that 777 is not a proper solution, I just wanted to see the thing working and then figure it out from there. You are probably correct on the hosts issue, but i don't think its the cause of my problem as i'm using bind_host crunchyboy and they are both on the same machine. My firewall is turned off, but maybe something else is blocking it.

Comment: If you get a different result when the php-fpm is running (403 from backend) or not (503 from lighttpd), then the 403 result is coming from your backend.  You have omitted way too much of your config and ought to read https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModFastCGI  Perhaps you need `"check-local" => "disable"` or to use mod_rewrite to rewrite requests to your index.php.